# Getting Google Refresh Token with Laravel Socialite

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, google-api-php-client, laravel-socialite

Using Laravel Socailite to connect to the Google API and I am getting back a connection fine, however this access doesn't return a refresh token so my connection is timing out.

```
$scopes = [
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
          ];    
$parameters = ['access_type' => 'offline'];
return Socialite::driver('google')->scopes($scopes)->with($parameters)->redirect();
```

How do I get the refresh token back?

Comment: Im running into the same issue. Any luck yet?

Answer (score 11):

When you redirect your users to Google, set access_type to offline with the with() method when redirecting, like this:

```
return Socialite::driver('google')
    ->scopes() // For any extra scopes you need, see https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes for a full list; alternatively use constants shipped with Google's PHP Client Library
    ->with(["access_type" => "offline", "prompt" => "consent select_account"])
    ->redirect();
```

Comment: By default refresh_token is returned only on first authorization, by adding `"prompt" => "consent select_account"` we force it to be returned every time.

Comment: The refresh token doesn't expire though so you'd only need it the first time right?